# How to target each string type node in a contenteditable area and wrap it between tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following triggers come jQuery on `input` in my `input-content` contenteditable div.

```
"input #input-content": function() {
    // code
```

When I paste text, I end up with stuff like

```
"foo"
<br>
"foo"
```

I would like to get instead (only for string type nodes):

```
<p>"foo"<p/>
<p>"foo"<p/>
```

How to accomplish that?

Comment: What you mean end up with strings ""? I can't see any input value manipulation.

Comment: my first assumption is that jquery is going to abstract the text nodes automagically. You should parse using the Document api directly and step through the child elements.